Can thionyl chloride or similar be used as catalyst for Hell–Volhard–Zelinsky halogenation?
Since the mechanism for the Hell–Volhard–Zelinsky (HVZ) reaction involves a phosphorus trihalide in catalytic amounts solely to form the acyl halide of the reagent, couldn't a different catalyst be used, like $\ce{SOCl2},$ which is usually used for turning carboxylic acids into their corresponding chlorides instead of $\ce{PCl3}?$

It seems to have been done for chlorination. J. Org. Chem. 1941, 6, 360. "Chloroacetic and -chloropropionic acids were prepared from the corresponding fatty acids by passing in finely dispersed chlorine at 105-110°, in the presence of red phosphorus (3% of the weight of the fatty acid". The phosphorus and Cl2
presumably form PCl3. From an acyl chloride and Br2, an acid is needed for enolization. P+3Br2 ⟶PBr3+3HBr. Any source of HBr gas would be acceptable.
